# POLLHUP vs. POLLRDHUP?

Tags: linux, epoll

According to the [poll man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), the poll function can return POLLHUP and POLLRDHUP events.
From what I understand, only POLLHUP is POSIX compliant, and POLLRDHUP is a Linux non-standard extension. Howerver, both seem to signal that the write end of a connection is closed, so I don't understand the added value of POLLRDHUP over POLLHUP.
Would someone please explain the difference between the two?

Comment: It means the remote end did a partial shutdown of the socket and won't be sending any more data but can still receive.

Comment: @Shawn When you say "it", do you mean POLLHUP but not POLLRDHUP? Or POLLRDHUP but not POLLHUP? Or do you mean  they both mean this? Or what?

Comment: "it" is the added value of `POLLRDHUP`. Although for TCP, I don't see how the two events can be distinguished. TCP doesn't send any indication when the remote socket has closed for reading, only when it closes for writing.

Comment: @Shawn, Would POLLRDHUP ever be set for a file descriptor representing a FIFO?

Comment: @Barmar The indication that the remove socket has closed for reading is that it has acknoledged *our* FIN packet.

Comment: @Guett31 no, POLLRDHUP will not be set for a FIFO.

Comment: @mosvy That's not true. The ACK just indicates that the FIN was received and the socket is still open. But you can't tell the difference between fully open and half-closed.

Comment: @Barmar What's "not true"? That's how it works in Linux. When the remote end has acked the FIN, the kernel with turn the `SEND_SHUTDOWN` flag on the local socket. Please refer to the `net/ipv4/tcp_input.c` file in the kernel source. When the `POLLRDHUP` flag is set in `revents` but not `POLLHUP`, the socket is half-closed: you can still write but not read from it.

Comment: @mosvy I don't dispute that the receiver of the ACK does this, but I don't see how the ACK means that the remote end has half-closed the socket.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, when `poll()`ing a socket, `POLLHUP` will signal that the connection was closed in *both* directions.

`POLLRDHUP` will be set when the other end has called `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` or when this end has called `shutdown(SHUT_RD)`, but the connection may still be alive in the other direction.

You can have a look at `net/ipv4/tcp.c` the kernel source:

```
        if (sk->sk_shutdown == SHUTDOWN_MASK || state == TCP_CLOSE)
                mask |= EPOLLHUP;
        if (sk->sk_shutdown & RCV_SHUTDOWN)
                mask |= EPOLLIN | EPOLLRDNORM | EPOLLRDHUP;
```

`SHUTDOWN_MASK` is `RCV_SHUTDOWN|SEND_SHUTDOWN`. `RCV_SHUTDOWN` is set when a `FIN` packet is received, and `SEND_SHUTDOWN` is set when a `FIN` packet is acknowledged by the other end, and the socket moves to the `FIN-WAIT2` state.

[except for the `TCP_CLOSE` part, that snippet is replicated by all protocols; and the whole thing works similarly for unix sockets, etc]

There are other important differences -- `POLLRDHUP` (unlike `POLLHUP`) has to be set explicitly in `.events` in order to be returned in `.revents`.

And `POLLRDHUP` only works on sockets, not on fifos/pipes or ttys.